# Is there anyway do something like list[select_all] in turtle python?

Tags: python, list, python-turtle

So I am making a game in python turtle with a lot of clones in it. I've put different clones to different lists.

How can I do something like if turtle.distance(list[select_all])?

I really need your help because I don't want to write a line of code that's like a hundred letters long. Thanks.

Comment: can you clarify and perhaps send some code?

Comment: for what I understand you can just use a `for` loop

Comment: You might want to use the `all` or `any` function.  Would need to see some actual code though -- it's not clear what you envision `if ... list[select_all]` doing.

Comment: The for loop worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fleshing out a complete example, I think I'd not use `any()` or `all()` but rather use `filter()` to find the actual turtles that are within a specified distance of the target:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint
from itertools import chain

screen = Screen()

prototype = Turtle()
prototype.hideturtle()
prototype.shape('turtle')
prototype.penup()

red = []  # a bunch of randomly placed red turtles
for _ in range(15):
    turtle = prototype.clone()
    turtle.color('red')
    turtle.goto(randint(-200, 200), randint(-200, 200))
    turtle.showturtle()
    red.append(turtle)

green = []  # a bunch of randomly placed green turtles
for _ in range(15):
    turtle = prototype.clone()
    turtle.color('green')
    turtle.goto(randint(-200, 200), randint(-200, 200))
    turtle.showturtle()
    green.append(turtle)

yellow = prototype.clone()  # our target turtle
yellow.color('yellow')
yellow.goto(randint(-200, 200), randint(-200, 200))
yellow.showturtle()

closest = filter(lambda t: yellow.distance(t) < 100, chain(red, green))

for turtle in closest:  # turtles closest to yellow turtle turn blue
    turtle.color('blue')

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want an uber_list with all turtles in the game. I think you can use list comprehension with a list of lists as such:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5] #list 1
b = [6,7,8,9,10] #list 2
c = [a,b] # list of lists
d = [element for array in c for element in array] # get every element from every list
print(d)
#Prints [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

In summary: make a list of lists, then make a list comprehension with nested for loops. Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if the other answer is what you need this could be a more efficient way (if not please enlighten me)

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = a + b
```